# How can I change the setup.bash to match the Ros version

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now I have install the Ros jade, but I have a setup.bash from the version groovy, so when I get"source **/setup.bash", it tell me that can not find the file. What should I do?  I think this setup.bash is made from groovy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224527/how-can-i-change-the-setup.bash-to-match-the-ros-version/) by [Rancho](https://answers.ros.org/users/25665/rancho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-01-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-19**:
How was the original setup.bash created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming you have an old catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: Delete your catkin_ws/devel directory and the src CMakeLists.txt, then rebuild your workspace.:

```
cd ~/catkin_ws
rm -rf devel build install
source /opt/ros/jade/setup.bash
cd src
rm CMakeLists.txt
catkin_init_workspace
cd ..
catkin_make
```

If that doesn't work then maybe there is a deeper ros installation issue more information would be needed to solve.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rancho](https://answers.ros.org/users/25665/rancho/) on 2016-01-20**:
Is that mean I need to reinstall catkin? I am a new guy in Ros, so can you explain it more specifically?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-01-20**:
No, you just need to clear out built files created by earlier versions of ros, and then catkin_make will build new ones.  I'm making a lot of assumptions about what your issue is, if you can cut and paste the command line and error output into the question above it would be helpful.

**Comment by [Rancho](https://answers.ros.org/users/25665/rancho/) on 2016-01-21**:
This file setup.bash in the working space is the guy before me left, I think it was made in the groovy$rosbuild, not the catkin. So if I try to source the setup.bash in the workspace, it told me that the setup.sh in the /opt/ros/groovy/setup.sh is not exist.So, now what should I do,reinstall groovy?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-01-22**:
If you follow my instructions it is likely you'll run into incompatibilities in your code between groovy and jade you'll have to fix, but you'll probably want to do that eventually anyhow.  If you feel uncomfortable deleting those files rename install/devel/build and you can always bring them back.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-01-22**:
Re-installing groovy is going to mean the code ought to work and recompile, but I don't know how easy or hard it is to re-install groovy at this point, and possibly more than a few people here (including me) haven't touched groovy in years.